# Do all servers have one base OS, like in RED HAT openstack architecture?

Tags: networking, cloud, redhat, openstack, server-side

I'm a noob learning openstack. And The resources are all over the place tbh. I came across this image and would like to know one thing,
[image]
So, Suppose I have 100TB of storage and 10 server grade processors, and ram of 1TB, do all these resources make up of only one base OS- RED hat enterprise Linux? So, they sell resources to connect all the equipment and connect to install one single OS which can comprehend them all?
And Upon this, we throw an Openstack architecture so clients can use them as needed? Do we need as many NICs or the NICs virtual?

Comment: This image describes Red Hat's own OpenStack distro RHOP. Obviously, Red Hat's OpenStack uses Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but you can run OpenStack on other Linux distros and even on Solaris. However, I don't quite understand your question. What do you mean by "one base OS- RED hat enterprise Linux"? One server with RHEL, or several servers that all run RHEL, or several servers that all run the same version of RHEL, or something else? I am not sure what you mean by "resources".

Comment: I also don't understand your NIC question. What do you mean by "as many NICs"? How many? If I am not wrong, part of Red Hat's OpenStack solution runs on virtual machines, and all OpenStack services are containerized, so yes, plenty of virtual NICs are involved. It should also be possible to run a RHOP cloud on virtual machines (though it's not supported), in which case you need no physical NICs at all.

Comment: By the way, since Stackoverflow is dedicated to software development, a better place to ask this question would be Serverfault.com. How to migrate a question to another forum: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work.

Comment: @berndbausch this is what I meant. If I have several servers running RHEL, are they all combined in the case of openstack? Like in the picture. If my cloud  is full and I want to add more servers, do I just buy server grade equipment and install enterprise Linux and somehow connect it to the previous server? How to scale?

Comment: @berndbausch on the NICs, I mean- by definition(at consumer scale-like one laptop) we need a network interface card for one IP. And to act as an interface. So, in the case of cloud, are the IP addresses all mapped to real physical NICs or Openstack uses one big special NIC which has one public IP and all IPs hop through it?

Answer (score 1):

> How to scale?

As you say, you just add a server. Install RHEL or another supported Linux distro (it's best to install the same distro and version on all servers), then OpenStack and configure it. The new server will register with the OpenStack controllers and can be used for launching virtual machines immediately.

The process is a bit more involved when you run a cloud with baremetal instances (i.e. you don't launch VMs but provision physical systems), but in principle it's the same.

> by definition(at consumer scale-like one laptop) we need a network interface card for one IP

This is incorrect. You can configure multiple IP addresses on a single interface, even on your PC at home, even if that PC runs Windows.

An enterprise cloud requires connecting nodes to several networks. Usually, servers have several physical NICs, bond them together, and use VLANs or other multiplexing technologies to implement the networks. See [this blog](https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=614) (five years old, but the principles still apply today, and it's well-written) for a good example of a real-world OpenStack network architecture.

> Openstack uses one big special NIC

OpenStack can be deployed in many ways. It is not a shrink-wrapped solution. It can be used on servers with single NICs, bonded NICs, VLANs, normal networks, etc. Your statement is almost correct if you think of a typical deployment and a bond interface as a "big special NIC".

If you are interested to try this out at home, see the [OpenStack installation tutorial](https://docs.openstack.org/install-guide/). You will learn a lot.